# Navigation bar back button method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to navigate to the particular page in my application and i also dont want to create any custom back button for that.If I can override the method of the navigation bar back button so I can call the poptorootviewcontroller.so i can go to specific page. Anyone knows what is the method that is called by the navigation bar button and if we can use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this.. Write your logic in this native method.

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    // Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide the name and the implementation for the button method As there is no standard method ..

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)] autorelease];
```

implementation ..

```
-(void) backButtonPressed {
 NSLog(@"Back button presses");

}
```

Comment: ya... but i dont want to use any custom button.

Comment: @ kdeo_16: you will have to use if you wish to get the event on click ... you could use the same graphic for the button as seen in system back button ..

Comment: ok... do you know which method is call for navigation bar back button.. 'cause some IBAction must be there after all its a button know...

Comment: @kdeo_16: which method is called on Back only Apple knows that .... Use this workaround and the only one solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below code:

```
NSArray * viewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
if([viewController count] > 3)
{
    UIViewController * vc = [viewController objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: do you know that which method is call for navigation bar back button. for future reference